# Does $\int u^{+}_n \ u_n dx \to 0$ if $u_n\rightharpoonup 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $u$ be a function and we denote by $u^+ = \max\{0, u\}$ and $u = u^+ -u^-$. Now, let $(u_n)_n\subset H^1_0(\Omega)$ with $\Omega$ open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$ be a sequence such that $u_n\rightharpoonup 0$.
I am trying to understand if it is true that
$$\int_{\Omega} u^{+}_n \ u_n dx \to 0 \quad\mbox{ as } n\to +\infty.$$

I was thinking about the fact that the map $u\mapsto u^+$ is continuous so it should be true.

Could someone please tell me if my reasoning holds true or am I missing something? However, how the weak convergence $u_n\rightharpoonup 0$ is involved?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why should the integral exist, let alone tend to $0$?

Comment: Possibly I should write something like: "Suppose that the integral $\int u^+_n u_n dx$ exists. In this case, does it tends to $0$ if $u_n\rightharpoonup 0$?" Did you mean that?

Comment: Hint: think about $\sin(nx)\chi_{[0,2\pi]}$

Answer (score 1):

This is not true in general. You can take as example $u_n(x) = \sin\left(2^n\pi x\right)$ on $[0,1]$. So \begin{align}
\int_0^1 u_n^+ u_n \mathrm d x& = \sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1}\int_{\frac{k}{2^n}}^{\frac{k+1}{2^n}}  u_n^+(x) u_n(x) \mathrm d x\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} \frac{1}{2^n\pi}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi} u_n^+\left(\frac{x}{2^n\pi}\right)u_n\left(\frac{x}{2^n\pi}\right)\mathrm d x\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{2^{n-1} -1} \frac1{2^n\pi} \int_0^\pi \sin^2(x) \mathrm d x\\
&= \frac1{4\pi}
\end{align}

The proof that $u_n$ converges weakly to $0$ can use the same argument as : [Why $\sin(nx)$ converges weakly in $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150645/why-sinnx-converges-weakly-in-l2-pi-pi)